# substraction with date using case and date formatter to format it

Tags: mysql

i have three date columns --- `dob`, `colldate` ,`encounterdate`.

I want to do something like this :

if colldate is not null and not '0000-00-00' then subtract year,month from dob otherwise dob's year and month is counted.

then encounterdate  column is not null and not '0000-00-00' then subtract it from previously subtracted date otherwise dob's year and month is counted.

is there any good way to do this with query.

basically i want to transfer this condition logic from java code to query.so i get result directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `coalesce()` function returns the first of its parameters which isn't `null`. As soon as a `null`value is involved in a calculation, the entire result is `null`. Therefore we just reverse the logic.

```
SELECT COALESCE(
    dob - interval year(colldate) year - month(colldate) month - interval year(encounterdate) year - interval month(encounterdate) month,
    dob - interval year(colldate) year - month(colldate) month,
    dob
    )
FROM your_table
```

Comment: sorry i want to do like this subtract dob from colldate or encounterdate.not colldate or encounterdate  from dob.so we can edit this query to do this.

Comment: it's helpful to me.not fully but i solved my problem with help of it.Thank you